Llama Index stack "Cannot build index from nodes with no content. "
I am using Llama Index for the first time and I started with the tutorial here
I just followed the code example in the tutorial and ended up with the following code:
from llama_index.core.node_parser import SentenceSplitter
from llama_index.core import SimpleDirectoryReader
from llama_index.core import Settings
from llama_index.llms.openai import OpenAI
from llama_index.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbedding
from llama_index.core import SummaryIndex, VectorStoreIndex

import nest_asyncio

nest_asyncio.apply()

documents = SimpleDirectoryReader(input_files=["doc.pdf"]).load_data()

splitter = SentenceSplitter(chunk_size=1024)
nodes = splitter.get_nodes_from_documents(documents)

Settings.llm = OpenAI(model="gpt-3.5-turbo", api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY)
Settings.embed_model = OpenAIEmbedding(model="text-embedding-ada-002")

summary_index = SummaryIndex(nodes)
vector_index = VectorStoreIndex(nodes)

When I try running the code in my own notebook I get an error on the last line creating VectorStoreIndex(nodes). I see a stack trace where at the bottom of the trace, it complains  "Cannot build index from nodes with no content. ". Here is the stack trace

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/llama_index/core/indices/base.py:145, in BaseIndex.from_documents(cls, documents, storage_context, show_progress, callback_manager, transformations, service_context, **kwargs)
    136     docstore.set_document_hash(doc.get_doc_id(), doc.hash)
    138 nodes = run_transformations(
    139     documents,  # type: ignore
    140     transformations,
    141     show_progress=show_progress,
    142     **kwargs,
    143 )
--> 145 return cls(
    146     nodes=nodes,
    147     storage_context=storage_context,
    148     callback_manager=callback_manager,
    149     show_progress=show_progress,
    150     transformations=transformations,
    151     service_context=service_context,
    152     **kwargs,
    153 )

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/llama_index/core/indices/vector_store/base.py:75, in VectorStoreIndex.__init__(self, nodes, use_async, store_nodes_override, embed_model, insert_batch_size, objects, index_struct, storage_context, callback_manager, transformations, show_progress, service_context, **kwargs)
     68 self._embed_model = (
     69     resolve_embed_model(embed_model, callback_manager=callback_manager)
     70     if embed_model
     71     else embed_model_from_settings_or_context(Settings, service_context)
     72 )
     74 self._insert_batch_size = insert_batch_size
---> 75 super().__init__(
     76     nodes=nodes,
     77     index_struct=index_struct,
     78     service_context=service_context,
     79     storage_context=storage_context,
     80     show_progress=show_progress,
     81     objects=objects,
     82     callback_manager=callback_manager,
     83     transformations=transformations,
     84     **kwargs,
     85 )

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/llama_index/core/indices/base.py:94, in BaseIndex.__init__(self, nodes, objects, index_struct, storage_context, callback_manager, transformations, show_progress, service_context, **kwargs)
     92 if index_struct is None:
     93     nodes = nodes or []
---> 94     index_struct = self.build_index_from_nodes(
     95         nodes + objects  # type: ignore
     96     )
     97 self._index_struct = index_struct
     98 self._storage_context.index_store.add_index_struct(self._index_struct)

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/llama_index/core/indices/vector_store/base.py:308, in VectorStoreIndex.build_index_from_nodes(self, nodes, **insert_kwargs)
    300 if any(
    301     node.get_content(metadata_mode=MetadataMode.EMBED) == "" for node in nodes
    302 ):
    303     raise ValueError(
    304         "Cannot build index from nodes with no content. "
    305         "Please ensure all nodes have content."
    306     )
--> 308 return self._build_index_from_nodes(nodes, **insert_kwargs)

I tried printed the nodes before this line and saw that the nodes did have content, and I infact looped through each node checking if it has content and it did. Here is how I checked
for node in nodes:
    if node.get_content() == "":
        print("Empty node")

Any help is much appreciated :)
